# drawTextInRect: in UITextView class

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uitextview

I use the drawTextInRect: method in the UITextField class to create outlined text (text with a black border/store effect).

But I need something similar to create the same outlined text in a UITextView, but the drawTextInRect: method is not included here. How can I do this for a textView?

This is the code I use in the UITextField class:

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 1);
    CGContextSetLineJoin(c, kCGLineJoinRound);

    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(c, kCGTextFill);
    self.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [super drawTextInRect:rect];

    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(c, kCGTextStroke);
    self.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [super drawTextInRect:rect];
}
```

How can I create a similar solution for a textView in a UITextView class?

Answer (score 1):

Are you targeting iOS 6.0+? 
Something like this should work, perhaps:

```
        NSAttributedString *yourString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Your text" attributes:@{
                                          NSStrokeColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor],
                                          NSStrokeWidthAttributeName:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],
                                          NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.0f]
                                          }];
        yourTextField.attributedText = yourString;
```

Enjoy

Comment: How can I set the fill color? The color inside the stroke? Because here it turns out clearColor automatically

Answer (score 0):

Peter, use negative value for NSStrokeWidthAttributeName. In this case you can set any fill color for text.

```
    NSAttributedString *yourString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Your text" attributes:@{
                                              NSStrokeColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor],
                                              NSStrokeWidthAttributeName:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:-1.0],
                                              NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.0f],
                                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor greenColor]
                                              }];
            yourTextField.attributedText = yourString;
```